# Average attempts until guessing 4 digit pin correctly

Tags: probability

If we have a 4 digit pin (so 10000 combinations --> 10^4), then on average how many pin attempts would it take to break the code.

I have 
p = 1/10000

at first glance I would say 5000; however if I try using geometric distribution, I get 6931 because the cumulative distribution is .5 at that number. Which is the best way to think about this?

Answer (score 1):

Geometric distribution means you try codes entirely at random, including codes you have *already tried earlier*. Naturally that will lead to you taking longer to get it right.

In addition, "Number of attempts needed to reach probability $0.5$ of having guessed the code" and "Expected number of attempts to guess code" are, a priori, different quantities.

Comment: That makes sense, so would the average even be where the cumulative distribution is .5 or would the actual number be closer to 10,000 if the codes can be tried at random.